# Аргументы функций

Tags: perl

Допустим у меня есть код :

```
sub test {
    my $var = shift;
    $$var = reverse $$var;
}
my $name = 'Test';
test \$name;
print $name;
```

И результат работы скрипта : **tseT** , что вполне обоснованно и понятно .

Но почему код :

```
sub test { $_[0] = reverse $_[0];}
my $name = 'Test';
test $name;
print $name;
```

Тоже выводит : **tseT**  , я не могу понять .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Аргументы, передаваемые в подпрограмму, находятся в массиве *[[[@_](/users/316/_cm_)](/users/316/_cm_)](/users/316/_cm_)*. Массив *[[[@_](/users/316/_cm_)](/users/316/_cm_)](/users/316/_cm_)* имеет локальную область видимости, но его элементы являются псевдонимами для реальных скалярных параметров. В частности, если элемент *$_[0]* изменяется, соответствующий аргумент тоже изменяется (или возникает ошибка, если его нельзя изменить). Если аргумент - это элемент массива или хеша, который не существовал в момент вызова функции, этот элемент создается только тогда, когда (и если) он изменяется или берется ссылка на него. (Некоторые ранние версии Perl создавали элемент независимо от того, присваивалось ли ему значение).

Присваивание всему массиву *[[[@_](/users/316/_cm_)](/users/316/_cm_)](/users/316/_cm_)* убирает такое поведение псевдонимов и не изменяет никаких аргументов.

(c) Вольный перевод perldoc perlsub.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что аргументы передаются по ссылке. Такая особенность Перла.
Даже не то чтобы по ссылке, а переменные $*[0] и $name становятся синонимами. И даже если внутри ПП локальной переменной $tmp присвоить $*[0] (my $tmp =  $*[0]), то и $tmp может ссылаться на $*[0]. Такие вот чудеса.

Comment: `sub test{
 my $var = $_[0];
 $var = reverse $var;
}
my $name = 'Test';
test $name;
print $name;`

Выводит: Test
UPD : добавил пропущенный вызов функции

Comment: надо писать
   print test $name;

Comment: Вы не поняли , здесь переменная , которую я передал в качестве аргумента (извиняюсь пропустил вызов test()) в функцию , не изменила своё значение . :)

Comment: Да, и у меня также. Но у меня был такой случай, может версия Перла была другой, может ещё что-то, но приходилось выворачиваться, даже не помню как вывернулся, но вывернулся.

Comment: @Error Ваша Error в том, что `$_[0]` Вы не модифицируете.

Comment: Ну так и вопрос был в этом , почему когда я модифицирую $_[0] , изменяется переменная - аргумент

Comment: Смотрите ответ @odmink0. Или perldoc perlsub.